An ESP32 DEVKIT V1 easily fried by hooking up Vin to 12V
I got myself an ESP32 and fried it on the first day!
I was confused about the supply voltage. I thought I had to hook it up to 3.3V which I didn't have. Then in the datasheet I saw the Vin pin 19 described as 7-12V. That in itself made me doubt I could drive it from one of my many 5V sources. So I thought maybe I hook it up to 12V (nominally) but that instantly fried the small helper chip below the AMS1117 (smoke coming out).
So I am completely confused why that pin is said to have a rating of 7-12V if it can actually run with 5V and 12.something V (nominally 12V) fries the whole board?

Polarity may perhaps have been incorrect. || Voltage rating of some of the ic's labeled at ams-1117 are very marginal and 12 volts is risky.

how do you know that you connected it to 12 V?

@jsotola I had a 12V power supply and wired it correctly. I did measure (afterwards) and found that it was really 12.something (like 12.6V alas, "nominally".

I'm not sure I would trust that datasheet. Here's the official Espressif datasheet from their website for that board, (or a very similar one, this is the V4) https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-dev-kits/en/latest/esp32/esp32-devkitc/user_guide.html#power-supply-options Power supply options include USB, 5V through the 5V pin and 3.3V through the 3.3V pin. The photo beside the description in your website indicates Pin 19 as "Vin 5V". I've never seen 12V as an option to power this style of microcontroller, though I'm sure they do exist, they're rare.

"input voltage" and "supply voltage" aren't necessarily the same thing.
